# Real-time timer on Android

Tags: android, timer

In what way that I can have a real-time timer for task scheduling on Android?

Currently I am using Java.util.timer for my real-time application? However, the timer is missing firing when garbage collection is running or other other stuff. The description on java.util.timer says "this class does not offer guarantees about the real-time nature of task scheduling.". Then, which class that I should use on Android then? Or are there any other approach to have a real-time guarantee timer on Android?

Forgot to mention that the timer that I need is at 20 - 40 milliseconds precision level. That means, I need it to fire every 20 - 40 milliseconds.

Answer (score 1):

```
Handler.postDelayed(Runnable r, long delayMillis);
```

Does not have a note about whether or not it guarantees it to happen on time. I've used this mechanism before and never noticed any inconsistency with it. However, i've only used it for relatively short intervals (less than a minute) If you are looking for something farther out than that I would suggest you take a look at the AlarmClock application in the Android source. That will probably give you a good approach. That being said if you are looking for extreme precision(down to seconds or farther) I doubt you're going to be able to find anything with guarantees. There are too many things that could be going on that could cause potential misfires.

Comment: won't the postdelayed run when the UI is ready? meaning that if the UI is busy this runnable will still be a little late?

Comment: Forgot to mention that the timer that I need is at 20 - 40 milliseconds precision level. That means, I need it to fire every 20 - 40 milliseconds.

Comment: What is your action? Will it be affecting the UI at all? If not you should be doing it in its own thread anyway.

Comment: Tim, Every time the timer is fired, it is going to notify another thread (NOT GUI thread) to generate output data. I need the timer to fire every 20 millisecond as precisely as possible.

Comment: I would think you should be able to put the timer into another thread too then as long as it isn't updating something in UI. But honestly Im not sure you're going to be able to something checking 50 times per second and have it work 100%.Check out CountdownTimer object, I have no experience with it but maybe it is a bit better than postDelayed.